# Adding sets of integers to an array decreasing size of each set added by half

Tags: java, arrays, insertion

I have two arrays and I want to insert bits of the first array into the second

array1: {1,2,3,4,5,6}

array2: {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}

My target is add half+1 of the numbers from the first array into the second array for the first iteration
And then half of the remaining numbers for each further iteration:
e.g.

1st iteration: {-1,-1,-1,1,2,3,4}

Second iteration: {-1,5,6,1,2,3,4}

the input data to be processed consists of exactly N positive integers, where
N = 2^M − 2 and M = 3, 4, 5. That is, N = {6, 14, 30}.

I have the code that creates the first iteration:
e.g.

```
for (int i1 = 0, i2 = Array2.length/2; i1 < ((Array2.length/2)+1) && i2 >=0 ;i1++, i2++) {
            Array2[i2] = Array1[i1];
        }
```

However to generate the second iteration I am having a lot of trouble.
If anyone can give me some advice on how to accomplish this I will really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it simpler, just try this:

```
    int[] array1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14};
    int[] array2 = {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1};

    int a1 = array1.length;
    int a2 = array2.length - 1;
    int j = 0;

    while (a1 > 1) {
        a1 = a1 / 2;
        int l = j;
        for (int i = j; i <= l + a1;) {
            array2[a2 - i] = array1[2*l + a1 - i];
            j = ++i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array2));
```

**OUTPUT:** `[-1, 13, 14, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`.

Note: you may need to check the length of your second array to be greater than first one, I assumed it is.

Comment: Yes the second array is to be 1 bigger then the first array

Comment: Ive been playing around with your code and found a problem with it. while it works for the example when applying to an array of length 14 it does not behave how i want it

eg. {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14} should turn into:

{-1,13,14,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} but in yours it does this:

{-1,9,10,11,12,13,14,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}

Any idea how to get it to perform in the desired manner?

Comment: the problem is you didn't clarified what you want well. you told : _My target is add half+1 of the numbers from the first array into the second array for the first iteration And then half of the remaining numbers for each further iteration_ , I thought you want to do it in two steps

Comment: OK, just let me to edit the answer and do it for you

Comment: My apologies I used a simple array example to make it easier to understand. I should have worded my question better. Im new to Stackoverflow so am learning! Thank you for your help!

Comment: I really appreciate the effort and you are really helping me get closer to what I want. The only problem is that the new way increments 1 number at a time. My specification is that for the first iteration it takes (N/2)+1 numbers and then each consecutive iteration it adds half of what the previous iteration added to the second array.  {-1,3rd iteration(13,14),2nd iteration:(9,10,11,12),1st iteration:(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)}

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the items from Array1 when they are inserted into Array2, leaving you with (5,6). For the next iteration, you could loop from length/4 to length/2. In theory, that should do it. 
so

```
for (int i1=0, i2 = Array2.length/4; i1<((Array2.length/4)+1 && i2>0;i1++,i2++)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: That's what I thought at first but it makes the program very specific. It also needs to fit the 2^m-2 criteria so that it can deal with longer arrays as well

Comment: Moreover doing array.length/4 only takes the first two numbers in the array so you would get  {-1,1,2,1,2,3,4}

Comment: It would, except I suggested removing the previously inserted elements from A1. You are correct in the sense that it would be a very specific instance though.